# Is there a min condition for a container to continue running?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-run

Why does the container exit when the entry point specifies to run a command in the background?
E.g. if I run `docker run -d ubuntu bash -c "sleep 12000&"` the container exits. If I run `docker run -d ubuntu bash -c "sleep 12000"` the container continues to run.
Isn't a process in the background sufficient to keep the container running?
Why does the `sleep` running in the background or foreground affect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Docker's mans, container is supposed to be running while

> the container’s primary process (PID 1) is running

In your case primary process `bash` and container "runs" until this process exits.

Comment: If I do `bash -c "sleep 12000&"` sleep should still be running no? In docker ps though it does not show up

Comment: No, `sleep` goes to background and caller's script terminates, thus container gets shutdown

Comment: Yes that is my question. Background process can not keep the container running? Why not?

Comment: Because of docker daemon's criteria of whether the container is running is that main process is active. If you want to keep container active, setup your main process to keep idle while background service is working

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by grapes, the condition is that PID 1 is running.

The container is designed to be short-lived and specialized in one task (microservice) which runs as PID 1 in the foreground. Background is of course useful for things like ssh, but the container has to have a main job.

Most service can be run both on foreground or background (deamonized)

PS. if you have to keep a container alive, use `tail -f /dev/null` as `CMD`

Answer (score 1):

A simple criterion might be the following: if you run a command locally and it immediately returns and gives you a shell prompt back, then if you run that command as the main process in a container, the container will immediately exit.

Usual best practice is to have a container run some process, like a network server, as a *foreground* process, and when that server exits the container is done.  In the ideal case the container is totally autonomous: once you `docker run` it, it does its thing without any user intervention.  (In this model a plain Ubuntu container, with no software installed, that only `sleep`s, isn’t that interesting.)